# EMail /GMail client is not displaying table in android

Tags: android, email

In my application i am providing an option for "Reply".When user clicks on "Reply",then am launching the Chooser Dialog which contains all mail clients.I am passing the data as HTML content.if the HTML conatins table then it is comming as paragraphs .